# Collaborative Filtering Using Multiple Features

Tags: machine-learning, similarity

I am looking to create a recommendation system for content. The content can be likened to an instagram post (contains a caption, hashtags, an image, etc.). I want to use user-based collaborative filtering N features to compute similarity between users.

I created a score for each post a user has interacted with (using likes, views, and a few other metrics) and built a user-item matrix (if thinking of a DataFrame -- a pivot table where the indices are users, columns are items, and each cell contains a score for user-item pair). Then, I use cosine similarity to find similar users based on their scores for each item.

Currently, this user-item matrix is 2d and uses a scalar (composite score) for each user-item pair to compute similarity between users.

I want to know:

(1) How can I create an n-dimensional user-item matrix where I take into account more features like location, age, etc.? Is it as simple as having an array of values in each cell, rather than a scalar? And still using cosine similarity as the similarity measure between users?

(2) I am curious to address the issue of a cold start -- new users/new posts -- using latent factor modeling. The factors I would want to use include unstructured text (think of hashtags for a post -- this set is ever increasing. My concern is that the number of latent factors will grow indefinitely, and this makes them unsuitable for this kind of issue.

Also from what I understand: For the matrix factorization technique I still need an MxN rating matrix (where M is number of users and N is number of items). In this case, doing a combination of (1) and (2) does not seem like it would work unless I stick to a single composite score for each user-item pair(taking into account all the features I want to include using some kind of weighted scoring formula).

Maybe Ive over complicated this problem in my mind, so any clarification or advice is greatly appreciated.